# Use of UNION when creating tables

Tags: mysql, union

Database-1

```
create table sample (
  id INT, 
  nm VARCHAR(10)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
UNION=(for tables from another databases);
```

So, when we do union what actually it meance?
Please explain, I am getting confusing for this type of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks close to the syntax for creating a `merge table`, but it has the engine type wrong.  Your statement will ignore the union clause and simply create a new, empty table. In order to create `merge table` you need to specify `ENGINE=MERGE`.

[14.3 The MERGE Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html)

> The MERGE storage engine, also known as the MRG_MyISAM engine, is a
>   collection of identical MyISAM tables that can be used as one.

The tables you specify in the `UNION` clause there, must all be identical - ie, having the same index and column specification, and they must all be in the same order in each table.

After that, can you query your merge table and access the data from all of the tables that form it.

You can also insert into your merge table, which is something you cannot do with a view:

> You can optionally specify an INSERT_METHOD option to control how
>   inserts into the MERGE table take place. Use a value of FIRST or LAST
>   to cause inserts to be made in the first or last underlying table,
>   respectively. If you specify no INSERT_METHOD option or if you specify
>   it with a value of NO, inserts into the MERGE table are not permitted
>   and attempts to do so result in an error.

Anyway, the doco has the rest of the information if you want to peruse more - I've never felt the need to use this type of table.

Example:

```
mysql>
mysql> create table t2 (
    ->   id integer primary key auto_increment,
    ->   val char(20)
    -> ) engine=myisam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into t1(val) values ('table1 a'), ('table1 b');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into t2(val) values ('table2 a'), ('table2 b');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> create table mt (
    ->   id integer primary key auto_increment,
    ->   val char(20)
    -> ) engine=merge union=(t1,t2) insert_method=last;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql>
mysql> select * from mt;
+----+----------+
| id | val      |
+----+----------+
|  1 | table1 a |
|  2 | table1 b |
|  1 | table2 a |
|  2 | table2 b |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into mt(val) values ('12345');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mt;
+----+----------+
| id | val      |
+----+----------+
|  1 | table1 a |
|  2 | table1 b |
|  1 | table2 a |
|  2 | table2 b |
|  3 | 12345    |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from t2;
+----+----------+
| id | val      |
+----+----------+
|  1 | table2 a |
|  2 | table2 b |
|  3 | 12345    |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you tell me If the created table have some data and the same data as in the table which we have in UNION field. so the result?

Comment: @Pratiksha See the example I just added - creating a merge table gives you access to all of the data in all of the tables in the union clause.

Comment: If suppose I used Engine=MyISM when creating 'mt' table then It will gives me empty set.

Comment: correct - the union clause in that instance would have no effect.

Comment: So, When we used Engine=MyISM and we want to UNION then, It will act like view?

Comment: You can't create a table, with a union clause unless it is a merge table. There is no table with a myisam engine that does what is explained here.

Comment: One last question is If table 'mt' is a view here then?

Comment: its not a view, because you can insert into it

Comment: Nope. I am asking that, if 'mt' is view here then what will happen?

Comment: And that's what i said - no, it is not a view, because you can insert into it. I updated the example in the answer to demonstrate that. You can't insert into a view, you CAN insert into a merge table